# How to modify/change the rectangle a TextView has, to something else

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

**UPDATE:** Updates added. Please check further.

I am trying to achieve something like this with my text view (The red portion):

[image]

This is to get a layout like this:

[image]

I subclassed TextView and added some code after some reading about how Views draw themselves, but I am not able to get the desired result.

From my code, the text goes in the background, and the drawable is covering it.
I have used `ShapeDrawable` and `PathShape` too.
What I am able to get is this:

[image]

**UPDATE:** The problem of the text being drawn behind the shape was solved by @malimo's suggestion, but the question still remains the same.
I could use the 9-patch solution or could have drawn a bitmap to mask things, but the whole layout will be put inside a scroller, and on smaller screens, is likely to scroll.
The background is a gradient, and doesn't scroll. So, when the content is scrolled with masks, the differences will be highlighted clearly and that's something I won't want to happen.

Is there an option where I can decide the whole shape the view draws itself into, and make it a path instead of a rectangle?
Will the view let me edit the way the rectangle is drawn?

If you look closely, on the right hand side of any the text views, the border is not a straight line, but a 45 degrees slant line. I also want the rest of the area left by the slant line, to be transparent, so that when it scrolls above the gradient, it doesn't look bad.
If it works, I'd apply it to other views (such as that button and Image View) also.

Can I be supplied the rectangle that the Base class of TextView uses, and modify that shape and give it back to draw?

The quick and dirty code that I have used is this:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView{

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attribSet) {
    super(context, attribSet);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(20, 20);
    path.lineTo(100,20);
    path.lineTo(130, 70);
    path.lineTo(20, 70);
    path.lineTo(20, 20);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    PathShape pathShape = new PathShape(path,getWidth(),getHeight());

    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(pathShape);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().set(paint);
    shapeDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    shapeDrawable.draw(canvas);

}

}
```

The XML where I am using this code is following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviewdemo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#FF99FF" >


<com.example.customviewdemo.CustomTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/customView"
    android:text="Hello, World!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where am I going wrong?
Or is there a better approach of going about this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi! just use a 9 patch png (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) as a background drawable for your textView and you should be able to achieve the desired result... if you really want to stick to your approach try to call 'super.onDraw(canvas);' after you called 'shapeDrawable.draw(canvas);'

Comment: Thanks for the tip @malimo , it worked. Now I have to figure out how to make the width of it dynamic. I can use a 9-patch, but I want it to be drawn as there will be a lot of views like these, and similar views have to join each other on these tilted sides to complete an effect.

Comment: @malimo I have figured out most of the things. Can you write your comment as an answer so that I can upvote/accept it?

Answer (score 2):

just use a 9 patch png (developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) as a background drawable for your textView and you should be able to achieve the desired result...

(if you really want to stick to your approach try to call 'super.onDraw(canvas);' after you called 'shapeDrawable.draw(canvas);')

regards

Comment: Although I didn't get any way to modify the rectangle that the view is being drawn in, calling `super` after drawing the ShapeDrawable solved one of the problem. Thanks!